# Additional type in open generic types inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

Recently I came across an interesting behavior of C# generic types inheritance. Imagine the following example:

```
class Foo<T> {}

class Bar<T> : Foo<T> {}
```

When we use closed generic types, their behavior in terms of inheritance is pretty obvious:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Bar<int>).BaseType == typeof(Foo<int>)); // True
```

But when we use open generic types, we get the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Bar<>).BaseType == typeof(Foo<>)); // False
```

Personally, I expected this line to print out `True`. So, let's take a look at the base type of `Bar<>`:

```
    Action<Type> discoverType = type =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type name: " + type.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Is generic type definition: " + 
            type.IsGenericTypeDefinition);

        Console.WriteLine("Generic ags: " + 
            string.Join<Type>(", ", type.GetGenericArguments()));

        Console.WriteLine("Types in generic:" + 
            string.Join<Type>(", ", type.GenericTypeArguments));

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    };

Type baseType = typeof(Bar<>).BaseType;
discoverType(baseType);

Type openType = baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
discoverType(openType);
```

The lines above produce the following output:

```
Type name: GenericsReflection.Program+Foo`1[T]
Is generic type definition: False
Generic ags: T
Types in generic:T


Type name: GenericsReflection.Program+Foo`1[T]
Is generic type definition: True
Generic ags: T
Types in generic:
```

So here we have a type (the first one) that was created from `Foo<T>` (the second one) by replacing `T` with `T` (unusual, but valid, because `T` also is a runtime-generated type). If we have another type that inherits from `Foo<T>`, then new base type will be generated:

```
class Another<T> : Foo<T> { }

Console.WriteLine(typeof(Another<>).BaseType == typeof(Bar<>).BaseType); // False
```

So, my question is: why do we need these "proxy" types between `Bar<>` and `Foo<>` and between `Another<>` and `Foo<>`, why open generic types can't be inherited from each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearer if you give the two type parameters different names - `T1` and `T2`, for example. Then the difference becomes clearer:

```
Type name: Foo`1[T2]
Is generic type definition: False
Generic ags: T2
Types in generic:T2


Type name: Foo`1[T1]
Is generic type definition: True
Generic ags: T1
Types in generic:
```

They really are different - `typeof(Bar<>).BaseType` has type arguments specified *by `Bar<>`) - it's just that you need `Bar<>` itself to have be concrete before you'll get a concrete `Foo<>`. In other words, `typeof(Bar<>).BaseType` is a *constructed* type, whereas `typeof(Foo<>)` isn't. See [`Type.IsConstructedGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isconstructedgenerictype.aspx) for details of this (it's another property which will give different values for the two types).

To put it another way, consider these three declarations:

```
class X1 : Foo<string> {}
class X2<T> : Foo<string> {}
class X3<TKey, TValue> : Foo<TKey> {}
class X4<TKey, TValue> : Foo<TValue> {}
```

Would you expect the base type of each of those types to be the same as `typeof(Foo<>)`? In the first and second cases surely it's `Foo<string>` rather than `Foo<>`... so why would you expect it to be different just because it uses a type parameter instead of a concrete type?

Comment: Jon, thanks for the explanation, now I've got it. I just expected the base class of generic definition of `X2`, `X3`, `X4` to be `Foo<>`. But now it seems clear for me that this base class is required to pass type arguments from `Bar<T>` to `Foo<T>`.